# Ruby SQLite database initialization

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite

I'm trying to access a basic SQLite database with Ruby, but keep getting a weird error.  The gems install without an error and I have the proper error, but when I try to actually run the code I get this error:

```
/home/--/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': near ".": syntax error (SQLite3::SQLException)
from /home/mastelj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new' 
from /home/mastelj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.¦rb:91:in `prepare'
from /home/mastelj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database. rb:134:in `execute'
^G Get Hel^O WriteOu^R Read Fi^Y Prev Pa^K Cut Tex^C Cur Pos from to_sqlite.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Program

```
require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.open('test.db')
rows = db.execute( ".tabes" )

for i in 0..rows.size-1
    puts rows[i]
end
```

Any idea as to what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.open('test.db')
rows = db.execute( "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';" )
# If you want just the table names do:
rows = db.execute( "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';" )
```

See more on the sqlite_master table here: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html.

Answer (score 1):

What should the SQL-command `.tabes` do?

If you use a valid SQL, you can use `db.execute`:

```
require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.open('test.db')
rows = db.execute( "CREATE TABLE [test] (  [test] CHAR);" )
```

If you want to get the list of tables you may select with sqlite_master.

```
require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.open('test.db')
db.execute( "CREATE TABLE [test] (  [test] CHAR);" )
rows = db.execute( "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';" )
rows.each{|tab|
  p tab
}
```

But I would recommend a database toolkit, e.g. Sequel:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite('test.db')

DB.create_table( :test ){
  String :content
}

puts DB.tables
```